# Скролл к конкретному элементу по центру блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице имеется **блок** с шириной и высотой ([ширина экрана]x248).
В этом блоке – большая SVG размером 1030х821.
В этой svg есть `<polygon class="current">`.
Необходимо произвести скролл в **блоке** так, чтобы этот `<polygon class="current">` отображался по центру этого блока.

Только один полигон имеет класс current.

При использовании такого кода центр рассчитывается не правильно.

```
var $scroll = $('.block');
offset = $('polygon.current').position();
var top = offset.top/2;
var left = offset.left/2;
$scroll.scrollTop(top);
$scroll.scrollLeft(left);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007530/how-do-i-scroll-to-an-element-using-javascript

Comment: Это не то. У меня другие условия для отображения.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте уменьшать число на высоту / ширину элемента делёныя на 2 у которого класса `curent`

```
var $scroll = $('.block');
offset = $('polygon.current').position();
var top = offset.top/2;
var left = offset.left/2;
$scroll.scrollTop(top - [высота элемента / 2]);
$scroll.scrollLeft(left - [ширина элемента / 2]);
```

Comment: Высота/ширина какого элемента? Блока в котором лежит SVG?

Comment: у которого класса `curent`, прошу прощения за неудобство

Comment: Неа. И если поставить класс ```current``` на другой полигон в другом конце svg – то скролл еще менее точный.